# No HDMI audio Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04 in a desktop computer connected via hdmi with an external BenQ GW2480E monitor. I have perfect video display but no audio output at all. I have checked a lot of possible issues and workarounds but none o them seems to work for me.

Somo extra info:

- `inxi -SMA` output:

Kernel: 5.4.0-29-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.1 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Gigabyte product: B450M DS3H v: N/A 
  serial:  
  Mobo: Gigabyte model: B450M DS3H-CF v: x.x 
  serial:  UEFI: American Megatrends v: F50 
  date: 11/27/2019 
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-29-generic.

- `alsamixer` output:[image]
- `aplay -l` output:

**** Lista de PLAYBACK dispositivos hardware ****
tarjeta 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdispositivos: 0/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], dispositivo 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], dispositivo 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], dispositivo 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0

Comment: After a fresh reinstall everything seems to be working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same motherboard and the HDMI sound is working (sound is coming out of my screen) but the front and back jacks are not.

I only installed a recent kernel, maybe you can try that too? I used [UKUU](https://teejeetech.in/ukuu/) but you can also download them directly from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ and install them with `dpkg -i`.

You should also try to upgrade your nvidia proprietary drivers.

For the record, here is the information of my system with HDMI sound working:

```
inxi -SMA
System:    Host: euclide Kernel: 5.6.11-050611-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.1 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop System: Gigabyte product: B450M DS3H v: N/A serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: Gigabyte model: B450M DS3H-CF v: x.x serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: F50 
           date: 11/27/2019 
Audio:     Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.6.11-050611-generic
```

```
aplay -l
**** Liste des Périphériques Matériels PLAYBACK ****
carte 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], périphérique 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], périphérique 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], périphérique 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
```

**I would be very interested to know if your jack are working?**

Comment: After a fresh reinstall, everything, including the jack, seems to be working properly, no need for new kernel reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding your user profile to the audio group? Adding your user profile to the audio group gives you full access to sound. Try:

1.Type in terminal:

```
whoami
```

that returns your user name.

2. Type in terminal:

```
sudo adduser <username> audio
```

where instead of <username> you'll type your user name returned from step 1.

3. Shut down and restart.

Comments: This may not be the most secure way to settle this, but if it works you'll know it's a user access issue which is one of the most common things that trips up Linux users.